Maximum of $\frac{2}{a^2 + 1} - \frac{2}{b^2 + 1} + \frac{3}{c^2 + 1}$ with $abc + a + c = b$ using trigonometric method

Let $a, b, c$ be reals such that $abc + a + c = b$.
Find the greatest value of the expression $(\frac{2}{a^2 + 1} - \frac{2}{b^2 + 1} + \frac{3}{c^2 + 1})$.

There are answers using different methods already (see What's the maximum value of $\frac{2}{a^2+1}-\frac{2}{b^2+1}+\frac{3}{c^2+1}$ given that: $abc+a+c=b$) , but I would like using a trigonometric variable change. The problem becomes (details are given later)

Problem. Let $\alpha, \beta \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Find the maximum of $$2\cos^2{\alpha} + 3\cos^2{\beta} - 2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)}.$$
Here we assume that we don't know the maximum $10/3$ and the maximizer (e.g., not aware of
this answer).

Remark 1. If we know that the maximum is $10/3$ along with the maximizer (e.g. aware of the this answer), wen can proceed based on these information. However, without knowing the maximum and maximizer, can we determine it by the trigonometric method?
Remark 2. Perhaps the scenario is similar to the following. Sometimes, we can motivate the solution via some way (even using computer, or guess), and write a solution based on the motivation. For example, in this handout, page 3-4, the isolated fudging, we hope to find $r$ such that $\frac{a}{a^2+8bc}\ge \frac{a^r}{a^r + b^r + c^r}$. We can motivate our solution  $r = 4/3$ using calculus, and the solution does not include any calculus. However, can we determine $r=4/3$ without calculus?
Here's my thought:
We have $abc + a + c = b \implies b = \frac{a + c}{1 - ac} \cdots (1)$ ($b$ is defined since $ac \neq 1$)
Let $ a = \tan{\alpha}$, $b = \tan{\beta}$ and $c = \tan{\gamma}$ where $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$
Now, $\beta = \alpha + \gamma$ from (1)
and the given expression becomes $2\cos^2{\alpha} + 3\cos^2{\beta} - 2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$
and it suffices to find maximum value of this expression I can't proceed further (as I have saw the solution and it's easier to prove something but without it how to arrive the maximum value would be 3) though I could claim and prove $$2\cos^2{\alpha} + 3\cos^2{\beta} - 2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)} \le 3$$

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

If you read the linked question, clearly it is shown the maximum is $10/3$.  Why would you think the "trigonometric" approach will give a max of $3$?

Further seeing that the answer includes $\tan^{-1}\sqrt 2, ; \tan^{-1}{(1/\sqrt 2)}$ etc doesn't give much confidence the trigonometric substitution is going to be any easier.

Let's call your function with all the cosines $f(\alpha,\beta)$. What happens when you set up and (try to) solve $\partial f/\partial\alpha=\partial f/\partial\beta=0$?

@GerryMyerson The possible problem is that he won't be able to solve analytically the two suggested equations.

@NN2, maybe so, but I'd like to see OP at least try it.

@NN2 whos this OP ? I hear it often at mse but don't know yet what does it mean ?

It means Original Poster (or Original Post) – in this case, it means you.

Let $f := 2\cos^2{\alpha} + 3\cos^2{\beta} - 2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)}$.
Using the double angle formula and the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
\begin{align*}
 f &= 1 + \cos 2\alpha + \frac32(1 + \cos 2\beta) - [1 + \cos (2\alpha + 2\beta)]\\
 &= \cos 2\alpha \cdot (1 - \cos 2\beta)
 + \sin 2\alpha \sin 2\beta + \frac32 + \frac32 \cos 2\beta\\
 &\le \sqrt{(\cos^2 2\alpha + \sin^2 2\alpha)[(1-\cos 2\beta)^2 + \sin^2 2\beta]} + \frac32 + \frac32 \cos 2\beta\\
 &= \sqrt{2 - 2\cos 2\beta} + \frac32 + \frac32 \cos 2\beta\\
 &= \sqrt{2 - 2\cos 2\beta} + 3 - \frac34 (2 - 2\cos 2\beta)\\
 &= -\frac34(\sqrt{2 - 2\cos 2\beta} - 2/3)^2 + \frac{10}{3}\\
 &\le \frac{10}{3} 
\end{align*}
with equality if $\cos 2\beta = \frac79$ and $\cos 2\alpha = \frac13$.
Thus, the maximum is $10/3$.

Seems interesting though what's that inequality being used here ?

@Ash_Blanc Do you mean C-S? $(x^2+y^2)(c^2+d^2) \ge (|xc| + |yd|)^2$

Yes it's very unpopular inequality that's why also very different from orginal C-S

Well anyways how come $\cos{2\alpha}.(1-\cos{2\beta}) + \sin{2\alpha}\sin{2\beta} \le \sqrt{(\cos^2{2\alpha} + \sin^2{2\alpha})[(1-\cos{2\beta})^2 + \sin^2{2\beta}]}$ so sudden ?

@Ash_Blanc Why sudden? It is the form of $p \cos 2\alpha + q \sin 2\alpha \le \sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$ where $p = 1-\cos 2\beta, q = \sin 2\beta$.

@Ash_Blanc We can use C-S of this form $(x^2+y^2)(c^2+d^2) \ge (xc + yd)^2$ which results in $\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)(c^2+d^2)} \ge xc + yd$.

thanks btw can we use jennsen instead of C-S too here considering the trigonometric functions ?

@Ash_Blanc I don't know. You can try. Here, there is the well-known form of $p\cos x + q\sin x$, and we can use $p\cos x + q\sin x \le \sqrt{p^2 + q^2}$ which is well-known (without using C-S).
